# Look Up with Multiple Returns Based on Column Header

Tags: arrays, return, lookup

Good afternoon,

I am working with an existing database that was created by a precedessor.  The system is not great but it is what everyone has always used and I am not authorize to change it.

It is a basic cost estimating spreadsheet.  Resources(people) are the column headers and activity descriptions are listed in the rows.  Hours are entered based on estimates for each person working on each activity.

I want to create a timesheet tab that will allow me to enter a persons name and it will return every activity they are associated with as well as the allocated hours for each.

Is there a way to search a match based on column heading (resource name), search down the column and if there is a value return the time value and activity description, which are located in the rows? And run this to return multiple values?

Thanks in advance.

K